# Automatic input in Ruby script?

Tags: ruby, bash

Im running this command from ruby script:

```
system "trad install"
```

This will prompt me three times for choosing y/n.

Is there a way to automatically choose y,y,n?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo -e "Y\nN\nN\n" | trad install
```

Comment: Great answer and simple answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can probably automate a run with [Session](http://github.com/ahoward/session) and Ruby's built-in [`pty`/`expect`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/pty/rdoc/index.html) (which seems to have no online documentation). (Dave Thomas has a few brief examples of `expect` and `pty` in recent editions of *Programming Ruby*, if you have a copy of that.)

However, I agree with [Dmitry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583276/automatic-input-in-ruby-script/3583639#3583639): it's almost certainly easier to adjust `trad` if possible.

Comment: I think expect is what you want to try.

Answer (score 0):

well, you might want to use

```
pipe = IO.popen("trad install")
pipe.write "yyn"
```

Not sure if that works, however.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that. If trad is your application, the best way is to add options to it.